# Apache solr date field in views

Tags: solr, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a custom date field in one of my content type `field_last_archived_date`.

[image]

There is a corresponding entry in the Apache solr field list called `dm_field_last_archived_date`.

Now there are two problems that I am facing

1. When I try to use this field in a solr view to sort the same, it gives me error "cannot sort on multivalued field."

[image]

2. When I try to use this field as an exposed filter to provide a date range, I'm not sure what date format should be given. I have tried formats like "2011-10-01T23:59:59Z", "2011-10-01 23:59:59", plain unix timestamp, etc. But all of them throws error "Invalid Date String:'OctoberAMCECESTAM+02:001_SunAMCESTE_1nd+02008601'".

[image]

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

`dm_field_last_archived_date` field is multi value field and solr is not provide sorting on multi value field.
To confirm behavior apply sort on single value field.
You can check multi value in schema file in solr it looks like

```
<field name="yourFieldName" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="true" default="defaultValue"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get. Solr will not sort on multi-valued field. But is there a way out, cause, I already have a huge number of data in that field, so cannot convert it to anything else.
Also any idea about my 2nd query?

Comment: You can do that but then you need to write your custom function like https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer